# Running parallel test suites using pytest without reordering tests in each of test suite

Tags: pytest, pytest-xdist

I am trying to execute multiple pytest suites at a time i.e parallel execution using pytest-xdist package using pytest.

For example, I've two test suites

1. test_one.py
2. test_two.py

pytest test_one.py test_two.py -n 2

However, this is randomly reordering my tests in both test_one.py and test_two.py and running tests.
Is there any way such that both tests suites run parallely but tests inside each suite in sequential manner ?

Comment: Based on [how pytest-xdist assigns tests](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist/blob/master/OVERVIEW.md) I think this would be 'interestingly non-trivial'.  But I could be wrong; bookmarking this question

Comment: Not *exactly* what you're looking for, but `--dist loadscope` or `--dist loadfile` might be close enough.  Why exactly does the order matter (other than neatness?)

Comment: --dist loadfile works . Thanks .